# one more time about: Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object, how to?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-app, content-script

here is my setup

background.js

```
var port = null;
function setPort() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
        port = chrome.tabs.connect(tabs[0].id, {name: "CONTENTSCRIPT"});
    });
}

// when i click on something, get the port and send a message
function clickHandler(e) {
    setPort();
    if (port) {
        port.postMessage({key: 'message', value: true});
    }
}
```

contentscript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
    if (port.name == "CONTENTSCRIPT") {
        port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        });
    }
});
```

what i am doing is clicking on a contextMenu button on random tabs and trying to send a meessage.

what happens is that first tine i click, nothing happens, no errors. the second time i click the message goes through.

if i switch to another tab, and click on the menu button, i get the `Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object` error. If i click again the message gets sent successfully

I've tried to use `var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "CONTENTSCRIPT"});` but that errors out with a disconnected port every time

ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact that `chrome.tabs.query` is asynchronous.

You execute `setPort()`, that immediately returns before `query` executes the callback and sets up port. At this moment, `port` is either null or refers to your previous tab's port.

Therefore, you either get no error, or an error because the old port is invalid.

After that happened, the callback in `query` gets executed and `port` is set up for the next communication.

---

So, to fix that, you need to send the message after the port is set up in the call chain. Example:

```
function setPort(callback) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
        port = chrome.tabs.connect(tabs[0].id, {name: "CONTENTSCRIPT"});
        callback(port);
    });
}

function clickHandler(e) {
    setPort( function (port) {
        if (port) { port.postMessage({key: 'message', value: true}); }
    });  
}
```

---

Edit: by the way, you're supposed to reuse a port, it's kind of the point. If you're re-establishing the connection every time, you're better off with `sendMessage`, though I suppose you only used the code above for testing.