# screen recording with chrome.desktopCapture stuck after choosing what to capture

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webrtc

im doing a small app and i would like to know if there is a way to view the screen you are "capturing"

the problem is that right now after i choose a screen to capture is it not showing the "stop sharing" white bar or anything like that, it just hides the choose frame to capture. this is a problem for me because i cant record anything.

this is the part of the code where  code:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener( function( port ){
    // listen for messages from the port

    port.onMessage.addListener( function( message ){
        // send back a "pending" answer on the port
        port.postMessage( {
            "answer": 1,
            "state": "pending",
            "requestId": message.requestId
        } );

        chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(["screen", "window"], port.sender.tab, function( id ){


            var response = {
                "answer": 1,
                "state": "completed",
                "requestId": message.requestId,
                "streamId": id
            };

            // send back a "completed" answer on the port
            port.postMessage( response );   
        } );
    } );
} );
```

is there a way to debug so i can know why is the sharing desktop part stuck?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can view extension by [inspecting it or using the debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging).

> **Inspect the popup**
>
> As long as your browser is in Developer mode, it's easy to inspect popups.
>
> 1. Go to the Extensions page (chrome://extensions), and make sure Developer mode is still enabled. The Extensions page doesn't need to be open for the following to work. The browser remembers the setting, even when the page isn't shown.
> 2. Right-click the extension and choose the Inspect popup menu item. The popup appears, and a Developer Tools window like the following should display the code for popup.html.
> 3. If the Scripts button isn't already selected, click it.
> 4. Click the console button (second from left, at the bottom of the Developer Tools window) so that you can see both the code and the console.
>
> **Use the debugger**
>
> 1. Set a breakpoint inside the code code for chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia
> 2. Refresh the page and check the debugger.

Also try using widely available debugging APIs such as console.log() and console.error() in your extension's JavaScript code.

Comment: i saw that im getting no errors or whatsoever but after checking a few times i realized that the extension is having an error: Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object but is not showing anything on the console most of the time

Comment: The problem maybe on the conversation takes longer that expected. Try reading through [long-lived connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943988/one-more-time-about-error-attempting-to-use-a-disconnected-port-object-how-to) and [re-establishing the connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943988/one-more-time-about-error-attempting-to-use-a-disconnected-port-object-how-to) to check the workaround about this error.